# How to make an image fade in once using plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using an AOS (animate-on-scroll) library in my html to help fade in the images, but javascript to trigger the actual fading-in. I want the image to fade-in when I am scrolling past, but not to fade back out when I scroll back up. The code below is what I've tried so far, but the image isn't showing up. I've seen a way to do this in jQuery, but I wanted to see if I could do it in plain JS. I got the image to show up and fade-in using the onscroll handler, but ran into the problem of it fading-in repeatedly if I moved back to the top of the page. Below is what I have using an event listener

HTML:

```js
//sets the point at which the image will fade in
    let pic = document.getElementById("pic");
    let characterCaption = document.getElementById("characters");
    let triggerAt = 100;
    function getPic() {
      pic.onscroll;
      let topOfImage = pic.scrollTop + triggerAt;
      return topOfImage;
    }

window.addEventListener("scroll", fadeInImage);

//attempt to fade in image at certain point and prevent image from fading in again 
function fadeInImage() {
      let currentPosition = window.pageYOffset;
      let topOfImage = getPic();
        if (currentPosition > topOfImage) {
          pic.style.visibility = "visible";
          characterCaption.style.visibility = "visible";
          window.removeEventListener("scroll", fadeInImage);
        }
    }
```

```html
    <img id="pic" src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/MZRJnpwAMIHQ5-XT4FwNv0rivw4=/1400x1400/filters:format(jpeg)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/19397812/1048232144.jpg.jpg" width="500px" height="650px" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-duration="2000" data-aos-easing="ease-in-sine">
    <p id="characters"> picture caption </p>
```

Comment: What is "*an AOS library*"?

Comment: https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

Comment: Can you please post a complete [mcve], including the html and the part of the script where you install the event listener?